# How to save a screenshot of a Form containing TRichEdit to a file?

Tags: forms, delphi, screenshot, delphi-2009, richedit

I use this code to save a screenshot of a Form to a bitmap file:

```
var
  Bmp : Graphics.TBitmap;
begin
  Bmp := GetFormImage;
  try
    Bmp.SaveToFile( _DestFilePath );
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

However, it doesn't seem to work well when a `TRichEdit` control is placed on the Form. Instead of a TRichEdit control and all its content, a white rectangle is saved into the final image.

How can I get a complete screenshot of a Form that contains a non-blank `TRichEdit` control?

I use Delphi 2009.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `GetFormImage()` fails, you should try to `BitBlt()` the Form's contents yourself, eg:

```pascal
var bm := TBitmap.Create(ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
try
  BitBlt(bm.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight, Self.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  // use bm as needed...
finally
  bm.Free;
end;
```

This successfully copies a Form with a `TRichEdit` for me.

Comment: You can't *safely* use the Form's `Canvas` from outside of its `OnPaint` event. Note that internally, `GetFormImage()` uses `TControl.PaintTo()` which simulates `WM_ERASEBKGND` and `WM_PAINT` messages to draw the Form and each of its controls onto the returned `TBitmap` canvas. So the original problem has to be with how `PaintTo()` interacts with `TRichEdit`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Could you please elaborate on the `Canvas` issue? Also, why do you want "Form" to be capitalized? English nouns aren't typically capitalized in sentence case.

Comment: "*English nouns aren't typically capitalized*" - a *Proper Noun* (a **specific** person, place, or thing) is always capitalized. A *Common Noun* (a **generic type** of person, place, or thing) is capitalized only at the beginning of a sentence. I guess it comes down to whether you consider a reference to a `TForm` object to be a *Proper* noun or a *Common* noun. I prefer the former. It just looks cleaner and easier to read, especially when talking about a specific `TForm` object.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I disagree. Surely you don't want to take the Dog for a walk in its favourite Park, even if it is a very specific dog and an equally specific park. And in Windows, you can have five buttons and a check box in a window (or a form).

Comment: (I disagree *respectfully*.)

Comment: So we agree to disagree. I'll leave it at that. This is an off-topic discussion.

Comment: The code kindly suggested by Andreas Rejbrand is functional, however, at least in Delphi 2009, you can't create a bitmap instance as shown in the answer, as the constructor doesn't take any arguments. You still need to set its dimensions though, which can be done once you instantiate it.

Comment: @MaxSmith: Correct, that constructor overload is rather new. You need to do `bm.SetSize(ClientWidth, ClientHeight)`. Also, inline variable declarations aren't possible in Delphi 2009, so `var bm :=... ` won't work. Instead, you need to declare `bm` in the `var` section before `begin`.